# Yii2 TimeStampBehaviour doesn't work

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii-behaviour

I've already spent many of hours, but I can't figure it out what is the problem yet.
I'm trying to implement a `TimeStampBehaviour` (and `Blamable`, but neither of them are working now). My model class:

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\BlameableBehavior;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\Expression;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "news".
 * .... property list
 */
class News extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'news';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['title', 'short_description', 'content'], 'required'],
            [['content'], 'string'],
            [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 128],
            [['short_description'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        // ... attribute label list
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'timestamp' => [
                'class' => 'yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior',
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_at', 'updated_at'],
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => ['updated_at'],
                ],
                'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
            ],
            'blameable' => [
                'class' => BlameableBehavior::className(),
                'createdByAttribute' => 'created_by',
                'updatedByAttribute' => 'updated_by',
            ],          
        ];
    }

}
```

I can save my model, every field is updated correctly, but the `created_at`, `updated_at`, `created_by`, `updated_by` fields are always empty.
My database table name is news, and it contains the 4 field: `created_at` and `updated_at` field's type is DATETIME (I've already tried with INT and UNIX timestamp, but it doesn't work), and the other ones type is INTEGER.

What could be the problem ? I've tried everything I've found with my friend, Google. :) Thanks.

**Update #1:**

My NewsController's create and update actions:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new News;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
        if($model->save()) {
            $this->redirect(array('index'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this -> findModel ($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if($model->save()) {
                $this->redirect(array('index'));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

**Update #2:**
I've 'accidentally' noticed, that the problem is exists if I try to update my model. I've just created a new model, and all of the four column is filled with the correct data.

**Update #3:**

```
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = News::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

`News` table structure:
[image: News table structure]

Comment: Could you update your question with action code responsible for saving this model?

Comment: What's the code for `findModel`?

Comment: You said `news` table contains only 4 fields but there are 3 different fields in your rules for this model. Is it working at all?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no clue why this doesn't work. When updating the model are you changing any field? If you are just clicking save without any change it will not update the database.

Comment: You'll not believe it, but I've found the same solution just now. :(
Sorry for my rookie mistake, I thought that the update is happening every time I call the update method.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I would like to 'accept' your very helpful answer, but in the comment section I can't do that.
If I can ask you to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are actually changing anything in your model's fields because if you are just clicking "save" button without any change, model is not updated in the database (there is no need to) and because of that TimestampBehavior does not work.

Comment: Afterwards it's absolutely logical mechanism by the way. Thanks.